# docker-compose wait to launch until a host filesystem is mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, nfs

The focus of this question is forcing docker-compose to wait to launch a *mysql* container until a host filesystem is mounted.  In my case the host filesystem holds the mysql database files.

For services that depend upon a *mysql* container, there are scripts, like *wait-for-it*, which run as part of a container entrypoint.  These scripts check for availability of services on network ports. But I don't see how to make a container launch wait for a file system to be mounted on the host.

When the host is booting, NFS and RAID filesystems might not come up as fast as containers start.  If the filesystem mounts on the host after the container starts, the bound volume in the container is not updated. Then the container ends up not having access to the mounted/bound filesystem.

Comment: Assuming that your system uses systemd (which is quite common), the solution is to make the `docker` service depend on the appropriate `.mount` unit for the filesystem. This will prevent docker from starting before the filesystem is mounted. E.g. as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount).

Comment: Great answer @larsks. I assume you mean to add `mnt-mountpoint.mount` to the end of the `After` line in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. I tested by unmounting the filesystem then stopping and starting the docker daemon.  Unfortunately, the containers all started with the file system unmounted.  I will test a reboot next.

Comment: A more thorough reading of the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount) revealed that I _also_ needed to add `mnt-mountpoint.mount` to the `Requires` line.  Now the docker service refuses to start if the filesystem is not mounted.  @larsks please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your system uses systemd (which is quite common), the solution is to make the docker service depend on the appropriate .mount unit for the filesystem. This will prevent docker from starting before the filesystem is mounted. Adding a dependency on a mountpoint is described e.g. [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount) over on https://unix.stackexchange.com.

For each filesystem listed in `/etc/fstab`, systemd generates a unit named `<filesystem>.mount`. For example, on my system, on which `/etc/fstab` contains, among other things:

```
/dev/tank/scratch /scratch xfs defaults 1 2
```

I see the following systemd unit:

```
# systemctl list-units -t mount |grep scratch
scratch.mount        loaded active mounted /scratch
```

We can make a service such as Docker depend on this mountpoint by adding something like the following to the `[Unit]` section of the unit:

```
[Unit]
Requires=scratch.mount
After=scratch.mount
```

The `Requires` directive means "when you start this service (e.g. `docker`), also start the units listed here", and the `After` directive means "start the named units before this one".

Comment: I believe this is the right answer, but unfortunately it does not work for me during system boot.  I think that is because systemd has a 4-year-old [bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4937) involving exactly this usage pattern.  I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how a utility like systemd, used by millions(?) of Linux hosts, could have such a bug.  Contributions of workarounds would be appreciated.  My Ubuntu 18 system runs systemd version 237.

Comment: Ah, bummer, I thought you indicated it was working. I'll take a closer look when I have some free time tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks.  It works when you stop and start the docker daemon _after_ boot, but not as part of the boot process.

Comment: Great answer! I haven't tested the solution thoroughly, but after a few reboots I can say that the docker.service indeed now waits for all NFS shares to be mounted. I hadn't had problems with missing volumes since then. The GitHub issue is still open though, so I don't know if this is really fixed or I just had some luck.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest level service is *mysql*.  Modify its entrypoint to exit if a directory known to be on the mounted file system is missing.

All dependent services can use the *dockerize* or *wait-for-it* scripts which wait for the mysql network port to open.

```
  mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.30
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ["bash", "-c", "touch /testdir/dir_on_filesystem/write-test && rm /testdir/dir_on_filesystem/write-test && echo 'Test for mounted filesystem passed' && mysqld --user=root"]
        volumes:
          - /mnt/mountpoint/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
          - /mnt/mountpoint:/testdir
```

If you can guarantee that `/mnt/mountpoint/mysql` exists on the file system prior to the first time the *mysql* container is started, then you can use that directory for the test instead of `/testdir/dir_on_filesystem`.

Note that this entrypoint test also ensures the filesystem is not mounted read-only.  When a RAID array is resyncing during system boot, it can start out in a read-only state until the resync has made some progress.  The check for writability is not strictly necessary since the mysql container will exit if it cannot write to its database files.

Comment: I thought a local filesystem folder is required to exist before you can mount a cifs or nfs share to it. If the share isn't mounted yet, wouldn't your entrypoint test be writing a file to the local filesystem instead of the remote share? I'm unsure that this is a valid test of a mounted remote share.